# function pointers using '<' as an operator

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I was learning function pointers and came across a piece of code [here.](http://www.newty.de/fpt/intro.html)
The `+` is suppose to work as an operator/function

```
void FunctionA (float a, float b, float (*pt2Func)(float, float))
{
   float result = pt2Func(a, b);    // call using function pointer
}



void FunctionB ()
{
   Switch(2, 5, /* '+' specifies function 'Plus' to be executed */ '+');
}
```

So i experimented with it a little and **this doesn't even compile.**

**Q. Why cant i use '<' as an operator here ?**

**Q. If not then does the user of the function need to write a separate code of compare two things whose comparision exists already...?**

```
template <typename T>
bool compare (T a,T b,bool (*compareFunction) (T ,T ))
{
    return compareFunction (a,b);
}

int main ()
{
    int a=5,b=6;

    if (compare<int>(a,b,'<'))
        cout<<"Sucess";
    else
        cout<<"Post this in stack overflow ";

  return 0;
}
```

Update :

Some of the comments advice me to use this

`(template <typename T, typename F> bool compare(T a, T b, F func))`

But if i use this then this would only work for `standard operators` like `std::less<int>` .
I want my function to work for both standard and non-standard operators (defined through their fucntions) both.

So the question still remains unanswered.

Comment: `'<'` isn't even a function.

Comment: so then is `'+'` one...?

Comment: `'<'` is of type `char`. It is not a function pointer. Neither are `'+'` or `'-'` or anything of a similar form.

Comment: then how come `'+'` is one...?

Comment: @PRP `'+'` is not a function either.

Comment: so u are saying the first piece of code also doesn't work..

Comment: That is correct. Neither will work; enable/read warnings.

Comment: @PRP Yes, we´re saying that. It´s easy to write a real function to add two floats and use it there, but `+` alone just won´t work.

Comment: then what about the second part of my question...?

Comment: Make your function fully generic instead of being a function pointer, since functors are not function pointers. (`template <typename T, typename F> bool compare(T a, T b, F func)`) Then you can use for example the standard functors `std::less`, `std::plus`, `std::minus`, et al.

Comment: The code that you linked in has a `switch` to decide which function pointer to return. You're looking at the wrong line with the `+` symbol.

    // this uses a switch
    Switch(2, 5, /* '+' specifies function 'Plus' to be executed */ '+');

    // this uses a function pointer. No '+' here.
    Switch_With_Function_Pointer(2, 5, /* pointer to function 'Minus' */ &Minus);

Comment: Simply :you cannot overload operators for built-in types.

Comment: @cdhowie but then will your way work for non-standard operators defined as separate fucntions as well...?

Comment: @PRP If you mean functions, yes, `F` will simply be deduced to be a function pointer.

Comment: @cdhowie pls compile all this into a good example and put is as a well formatted answer...this will also help other having same problem

Comment: @PRP I can't because the question has been closed as a duplicate.