# function pointers of standard operators

Tags: c++, function-pointers

This is a followup Question of [function pointers using '<' as an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606889/function-pointers-using-as-an-operator) which still doesn't have an answer.

This is very similar to the answer code i found here : [Is it possible to get the function pointer of a built-in standard operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644816/is-it-possible-to-get-the-function-pointer-of-a-built-in-standard-operator)

Q. In the above link `+` is used as a `std::operator+` so why can't i use `std::operator<` ?

**The aim is to not use the overloaded funciton with less arguments and instead replace with something from the `std::library`**

```
template <typename T>

bool compare (T a,T b,bool (*compareFunction) (T ,T ))
{
    return compareFunction (a,b);
}

template <typename T>
bool compare (T a,T b)
{
    return a<b;
}

bool m (int a ,int b)
{
    return a<b;
}
int main ()
{
    int a=5,b=6;

    /*
    * This Works
    */

    if (compare<int>(a,b,m))
        cout<<"Sucess";
    else        
        cout<<"Post this in stack overflow ";

    /*
    * This also Works
    */

    if (compare<int>(a,b))
        cout<<"Sucess";
    else
        cout<<"Post this in stack overflow ";

    /*
    * Adding this gives compile error.
    */

    if (compare<int> (a,b,&std::operator<))
        cout<<"sucess";
    else
        cout<<"Post in Stackoverflow "; 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: whoever marked it duplicate din't even read my full question....i have already seen the link u gave me..in fact i have referred it in my question itself...but stuff aint working dude...

Comment: From the second link: `Built-in operators (those for the built-in types) aren't real operator functions. So you can't have function pointer pointing to them.`

Comment: @PRP _"The aim is to not use the overloaded funciton with less arguments and instead replace with something from the std::library"_ There's well a reference what to use from the c++ standard library mentioned in the (now unlocked) dupe. Looks like you're looking for [`std::less()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can u give me a sample piece of code that serves as an example...a working piece...a complete novice here

Comment: Example: http://ideone.com/MmqSkg

Comment: @Brandon Great Great Help.....!!

Comment: The complete Example to my doubt is here http://ideone.com/8hgLmW...This is for any future people referring it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the difference between built-in operators and overloaded operators. Built-in operators are operators that have as operands only basic types (integers, booleans, floats, pointers).

E.g.:

```
int a = 9, b = 7;
a + b; <-- built-in plus operator
6 + 5; <-- built-in plus operator
```

C++ gives the possibility to define operators for user defined types (i.e. classes). `std::string` is a class (defined by the library, but that doesn't matter). So if we write this:

```
std::string a = "asdf", b = "qwert";
a + b; <-- this is not built-in operator.
```

In order for the above to compile there has to be a declaration and definition of a plus operator that operates on two objects of type string. It happens that the standard library defines such operator: [std::operator+(std::basic_string)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B). So this:

```
std::string a = "asdf", b = "qwert";
a + b;
```

is actually this:

```
std::string a = "asdf", b = "qwert";
std::operator+(a, b); <-- call to overloaded operator (see this as a function call)
```

Built-in operators **are not functions**. Overloaded operators behave like functions.
Built-in operators have **only** basic types as operands and their functionality is defined by the standard (you cannot redefine what `int + int` does).
Overloaded operators must have at least one operand of user-defined type.

---

Lets get to some practical examples:

```
template <class T, class Compare>
bool compare (T a, T b, Compare comp) {
   return comp(a,b);
}
```

I've replaced your function pointer with a template parameter. So this can be a function pointer, a function reference or a function object.

What choices do you have to call this with `T` as `int`? Well you certainly can't have an operator passed for `comp`. So you have to have a function or a function object (see link below).

```
// function
bool intCompareLess(int a, int b) {
  return a < b;
}

compare(3, 5, intCompareLess);


// function object
class IntComparatorLess {
public:
   // this is a function call operator overload
   bool operator()(int a, int b) {
      return a < b;
   }
};

compare(3, 5, IntComparatorLess());

// or don't reinvent the wheel:
compare(3, 5, std::less<int>()); // std::less is somehow similar with IntComparatorLess
```

what if you call compare with `T` as a user defined type

```
class MyClass {
public:
  int x, y;
};
```

Now you have an extra option: define a operator and pass it as parameter:

```
bool operator<(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
  if (c1.x == c2.x) 
    return c1.y < c2.y;
  return c1.x < c1.x
}

MyClass a, b;
compare(a, b, (bool (*)(MyClass, MyClass))operator<);
```

usefull: [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)

Comment: so what u are saying is there doesnt exist a function `bool operator< (int a,int b)` in the standard library

Comment: no there isn't. It is not permitted by the language.

Comment: then what is @πάντα ῥεῖ mentioning ad std::less () ...? in his comments

Comment: @PRP Follow the link I've placed for `std::less`. There's actually a set of functors, you can use as a replacement for the _missing_ standard operator functions. That's exactly what was explained in the answers for my own older question I had marked as dupe.

Comment: @bolov then how is this working     `if (compare<int>(a,b)) { }`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok...let me go through it

Comment: @PRP is it now more clear?

Comment: @bolov super cool example u gave....thanks a ton